# How to implement parent methods to activity and FragmentActivity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I am working on an android application,
and I have number of activities that extend from a custom activity.

Now I created a new FragmentActivity and I need the same functions that I have implemented in my custom activity.

How can I do that?

**Edit**

This is an simple example

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity
{
    protected void someFunction()
    {
        Log.i("TEST","This is a test");
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        someFunction();
    }
}
```

this is my FragmentActivity:

```
public class MyFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // here I want to use someFunction()..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java you can't extend more than one class. 
So I guess you should extend BaseActivity from FragmentActivity instead of Activity

Comment: Yes I know that and this is the reason that I asked, anyway I saw that in facebook sdk 3.0 FacebookActivity extends from FragmentActivity so I will do the same.
Thanks.